# Calculate number of in and out edges in a boost::graph vertex

Tags: c++, boost-graph, adjacency-list, edges

I've the following graph type

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, PathVertex, PathEdge> GraphStructure;
```

I insert some directed edges.

Now, for every vertex, I want to calculate number of in edges and out edges.

For now, I've discovered the m_out_edges structure

```
GraphStructure xGraph;

add_edge(0, 1, xGraph);
add_edge(1, 2, xGraph);
add_edge(2, 1, xGraph);

int iValue = xGraph.m_vertices.at(0).m_out_edges.size();
```

But I don't know if it's what I want, and there's always the problem of in edges that I can't calculate at the moment.

So, given an adjacency_list, how can I iterate through its vertices, and know how many are input edges and output edges, separately?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: If you use `bidirectionalS` instead of `directedS` you can use `in_degree(vertex,graph)` and `out_degree(vertex,graph)`. (only `out_degree` is available when you use `directedS`).

Comment: you should answer your question,for others :)

Comment: @llonesmiz Please copy & paste your comment as an answer so this question can be resolved. :)